# How to shift a React Component on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a static component that can be shifted below when I click the button to show below the component for which the button is clicked, and works same way for all buttons.

Right now I have 4 buttons. When I click the **NearbyPlaces** button I want that the **Essential** component to shift down and **NearbyCard** to appear above the **Essential** Component. I want all the buttons to work this way.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-matsumoto-7ox17l?file=/src/EssentialComponent.jsx

Above is my code.

[image]

I want to render this **Essential** component always and when I click the **NearbyPlaces** button I want that component to be rendered and **Essential** component to be shifted below.

[image]

Above is my **Nearby** component.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Investigate about scrollIntoView. You may need to use `useRef` too.

Comment: Do you want a transition to switch Components? Not clear about your question and the code can't run. Maybe you are looking for [useTransition](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usetransition)?